# Regression with linear trend goes mad

Tags: r, dataframe, panel

I want to define a function panel_fit which will perform panel fit for dependent variable (y), and independent variables (x). The panel regression should has linear trend within it.

I want to show you my work on the data following :

```
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
dep_var <- EmplUK['capital']
#deleting dependent variable - it's meaningless but, it's only for defining function purpose
df1 <- EmplUK[-6]

panel_fit <- function(y, x, inputs = list(), model_type) {
  x[, length(x) + 1] <- y
  x <- x %>%
    group_by_at(1) %>%
    mutate(Trend = row_number())

  
  varnames <- names(x)[3:(length(x))]
  varnames <- varnames[!(varnames == names(y))]
  form <- paste0(varnames, collapse = "+")
  model <- plm(as.formula(paste0(names(y), "~", form)), data = x, model = model_type)
  summary(model)
}
```

The error I get is :

```
panel_fit(dep_var,df1,model_type='within')

Warning messages:
1: In Ops.pseries(y, bX) :
  indexes of pseries have same length but not same content: result was assigned first operand's index
```

Do you know why I got such ? What should I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: please edit your code to add the call to panel_fit(). Are you missing a comma in `x[length(x) + 1] <- y` that is should it be `x[,length(x) + 1] <- y`?

Comment: I did update my question. I changed comma place but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: wag, `Trend` and `year` might have the same info (1 data point per year). Your Trend variable is just counting rows by company. Try removing one of them from the fit, eg `varnames[!(varnames %in% c("year", names(y)))]`. In general, try the code outside of your function, in this case `panel_fit()` so that you can check the details and experiment with solutions.

Comment: I adjusted your changes but warning still occurs